# How to find undeletable files that were removed?

Tags: files, rm

I just created a file:

```
touch myFile
```

Made it "undeletable":

```
chattr +u myFile
```

and removed it:

```
rm myfile
```

How can I get it back? What is the purpose of "u"? Is it used?

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: According to `df -T`: ext4

Comment: I find the increasing tendency to just ask than to think for one minute and enter "chattr +u" into google and just read one of the results, any of them. They all tell you: `the ext filesystems don't honor that flag`. If you are using another filesystem there is a big chance that searching for "chattr +u <your_fs_name>" will give you an anwer. Just wanted to note that ...

Comment: The manual says "The `c', 's',  and `u' attributes are not honored by the ext2 and ext3 filesystems as implemented in the current mainline Linux kernels." At least that's the manual page on my Arch system.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`chattr` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr):

> The 'c', 's', and 'u' attributes are not honored by the ext2 and ext3 filesystems as implemented in the current mainline Linux kernels. These attributes may be implemented in future versions of the ext2 and ext3 filesystems.

This is present in the July 2012 version of the man page, so I suspect the same is true for ext4.  My guess is that someone (the `chattr` developer?) either experimented or planned to experiment with these features, but they were never stable or complete enough for the mainline kernel.

Pity; I'd appreciate a `+s`.